# Can ActiveMQ Artemis connect to Oracle via JDBC using Kerberos?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, datasource, kerberos, activemq-artemis

Checking ActiveMQ Artemis docs/files I only found that `broker.xml` could be configured as per below for database connection (example):

```xml
   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core">
      <store>
         <database-store>
            <jdbc-connection-url>jdbc:derby:target/derby/database-store;create=true</jdbc-connection-url>
            <jdbc-user>ENC(5493dd76567ee5ec269d11823973462f)</jdbc-user>
            <jdbc-password>ENC(56a0db3b71043054269d11823973462f)</jdbc-password>
         </database-store>
      </store>
   </core>
```

Does anybody know if ActiveMQ Artemis 2.15.0 is able to connect to Oracle Database using Kerberos?

Comment: It's worth noting that ActiveMQ Artemis 2.15.0 was released over 3 years ago now. I recommend you use a later release, ideally [the latest](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/).

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ Artemis uses JDBC to connect to any database with a compliant driver. As far as I'm aware JDBC doesn't have any specific features or functionality related to Kerberos. Therefore, the Kerberos functionality will need to come from whatever JDBC driver you're using, and presumably the configuration for that functionality would be done through the URL or perhaps system properties.

According to this [Oracle JDBC driver documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html):

> The JDBC Driver can authenticate to the Oracle Database using Kerberos. For this, the Oracle Database Server has to be configured to support Kerberos authentication. Please refer to Oracle documentation on how to configure the Oracle Database for Kerberos authentication. Configure the following connection properties to enable Kerberos authentication in the JDBC Driver.
>
> - `oracle.net.authentication_services=(KERBEROS5)`
> - `oracle.net.kerberos5_mutual_authentication=true`
> - `oracle.net.kerberos5_cc_name=<path to the kerberos credentials cache file>`
>
> Additional configuration can be specified in a configuration file indicated by the system property `java.security.krb5.conf`. Please refer to JDK documentation for more information.

Try something like:

```xml
<store>
    <database-store>
        <data-source-properties>
            <data-source-property key="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <data-source-property key="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port/servicename" />
            <data-source-property key="connectionProperties" value="oracle.net.authentication_services=(KERBEROS5),oracle.net.kerberos5_mutual_authentication=true,oracle.net.kerberos5_cc_name=/opt/keytab" />
        </data-source-properties>
    </database-store>
</store>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there is no such thing as key="oracle.*" in data-source-property. Even if I put <data-source-property key="connectionProperties" value="{oracle.net.authentication_services=(KERBEROS5),oracle.net.kerberos5_mutual_authentication=true,oracle.net.kerberos5_cc_name=/opt/keytab}" /> still does not work as I still have in activemq process : Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied, although tested from oracle database and is connecting without username and password.

Comment: You were right about the incorrect `key` values. I've updated my answer to address that. However, I'm using a slightly different `value` than you. I've omitted the `{` and the beginning and the `}` at the end as they don't appear to comply with the [documented syntax](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp2/BasicDataSource.html#setConnectionProperties(java.lang.String)).

Comment: The fact that you're receiving `ORA-01017: invalid username/password` indicates to me a configuration problem in your environment. According to the Oracle documentation their JDBC driver does, in fact, support Kerberos. Therefore, you should be able to connect with the right configuration.

Comment: Managed with invalid username/password..it was from {} in configuration indeeed. Thanks...Now I have a new bigger one in artemis : Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain Principal Name for authentication. This might be from JDBC driver. I am using ojdbc11 and java-11-amazon-correto.  I do not know yet :(

Comment: If my answer has been helpful please mark it as correct or vote it up. Now that you've gotten past the first hurdle perhaps it's time to move to a new question.

Comment: Any feedback here?

Comment: All good with the answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it addressed your issue in order to help other folks who have this same question in the future. Thanks!